# Older version of Excel will not open XLSX files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, compatibility

I've been using an old version of Office 97 (with Macros disabled for security) for some time. Recently I got a new Windows 10 v1803 PC and re-installed Office 97. With the [Office 2007 Compatibility Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=33298) installed, `Word` opens every `.docx` file I've tried...but `Excel` always fails to open `.xlsx` files with this message:

[image: .xlsx file not recognised]

I have tried:

- Opening file in Google Sheets and exporting as a fresh `.xlsx` file
- Installed SP1, SP2 & SP3 for `Office 2007 Compatibility Pack`
- Renamed the extension from `.xlsx` to `.xls` (why this is supposed to work beats me, but I found this suggestion in an online search)

Always the same result of "Not recognised". This worked on my earlier Windows 8.1 machine. Any ideas?

#### UPDATE 1

Based on one of the comments, I upgraded my installation from Office 97 SR-1 to SR-2. However, the result is the same: Word opens `.docx` files but Excel is not able to open `.xlsx` files. The `Compatibility mode` for Excel has also been switched between `Off` and various `Windows XP` modes without helping.

#### UPDATE 2

Just installed Office 2000 on a new Windows 10 machine and the `Office 2007 Compatibility Pack SP3` works fine, opening both `.docx` and `.xlsx` files.

Comment: Does the file name contain any reserved characters? Does the file have 2 extensions (have you turned on show extensions)?

Comment: Ideas: Install a current MS Office version; install the free WPS.

Comment: Have you set Office 97 programs to run in Compatibility Mode? What if you run Excel.exe in compatibility mode (assuming Office 2007 compatibility pack is installed) and try to open the file from File - Open Menu?

Comment: note that a xlsx is a zip file of many xml files. rename it to .zip, and look at the details. my guess is that there is a feature used that the converter doesn't understand, or you don't have zip installed?

Comment: While you check out the file as @Aganju suggests, you may as well look at the version of Excel the XLSX was saved in (in `\docProps\app.xml`. It might be that the compatibility pack can't handle files saved with more recent version Excel than 2007.

Comment: @Aganju: Didn't know about `.xlsx` actually being a ZIP! I use 7-zip, does that matter? I extracted everything and the version of Excel my `.xlsx` was created with is `14.0300`.

Comment: @spikey_richie: Yes, file extensions are turned on. Why does Microsoft even have this silly feature of hiding the extension anyway?

Comment: @AlainD , if _you_ can extract the content of the zip, excel can too, so you are good with that zip version. In other words, _that_ is not your issue.

Comment: @Aganju: OK, thanks. I suspect its got to do with the fact that I need to upgrade to Office 97 SR-2 (have SR-1 installed) based on the answer from `harrymc`...busy looking into this.

Comment: The file format is only part of the change since 97.  There have been a lot of features and functions added since then.  You can translate the file format to something that Excel 97 recognizes, but that won't tell Excel 97 what to do with functions and features that aren't in its repertoire.  If it could, users would have no reason to upgrade.

Comment: A search online suggests that the compatibility pack only works for Office 2000, XP and 2003. I also stumbled upon an older version on archive.org that claims the most recent version doesn't even work for 2000, so 97 might not be supported either.

Answer (score 1):

The
[Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack Service Pack 3 (SP3)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27836)
is supposed to enable using the new format in older Office versions.

You should be using Office 97 SR-2 with all possible updates.

Better take backup of your installation before starting, just in case.

If Service Pack 3 is too recent for your setup, then there also exist
[Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack Service Pack 1 (SP1)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1285) and
[Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack Service Pack 2 (SP2)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12439).

Comment: Have tried SP1, SP2 and SP3 with the same issue...but just checked my Excel Help > About and am using `Office 97 SR-1`. That might be the problem, then. Wonder why it worked on Windows 8.1 then. Note that Word opens `.docx` fine.

Comment: Have now installed Office 2000 on a new Windows 10 computer and the `Compatibility Pack SP3` works fine, opening both `.docx` and `.xlsx` files.